# What is the difference between these two "pointer delete" operation in c++?

Tags: c++

if I want to delete a pointer and release the memory it uses, what's the difference between these 2 segments of codes? (in C++)

1.

```
delete p1;
p1=p1->next;
```

2.

```
int* remove;
remove=p1;
p1=p1->next;
delete remove
```

I tried both two and code 1 leads to memory problems, but I don't know why.

Could you tell me what happened after you "delete" a pointer?Does it delete the pointer itself? Or both the pointer and the stuff it points at? Or only the stuff it points at?

Thank you!

Comment: There is not difference as you have written them. Both have undefined behavior, just for different reasons.

Comment: `delete remove;` is undefined behavior, as well `p1=p1->next;` is.

Comment: damn I am new to this website. There should be "remove = p1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first snippet has undefined behaviour because in the second line you access an already deleted object. Your second snippet is fine. It does the same as the first snippet but avoids the UB.

Btw: The first two lines in your second snippet should be a single line `int* remove = p1;`. This is C++ after all, not ultra-ancient C. Never leave a variable uninitialized without a rock-solid reason.